# Arithmetic operations for Stackdriver monitoring charts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, monitoring-query-language

I'm trying to setup a Stackdriver dashboard for my custom metrics that my services provide.

In particular I'm starting with general `custom/grpc/time_ms` metric that is a gauge and have `status` label on it. I'd love to be able to set up a chart and alert for success rate of the metric(something like `count:custom/grpc/time_ms{status:OK} / count:custom/grpc/time_ms{*}`).

With my previous project I used Datadog and it was [pretty easy to do so there](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001415486-Performing-Metric-Arithmetic-in-Graphs-Monitors). But I don't see any similar functionality neither in the UI nor in Stackdriver documentation. So I was wondering if it's not documented or simply not supported?

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, however, still might be useful for new users of Google Cloud.

In 'Metrics Explorer' in Google Cloud Console there is an option to write a query with MQL (click `Query Editor` button).
MQL supports expressions which are described in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#expression).

The simplest example for dividing one metric by another would look like this:

```
{ fetch
    your_resource_type ::
    your_metric_1
; fetch
    your_resource_type ::
    your_metric_2 
}
| join
| div
```